# Vue JS: Forms are not getting cleared when router.push() method is executed after the logout

Tags: vue.js, flask, vue-component, vue-router, flash-message

I am using Flask as a backend and Vue JS as front end for my development. Vuex for state store.

In the logout() I am clearing the authentication token from localStorage via **store.dispatch('/logout')** and then using **router.push('/login')** to navigate to Login.vue. I find that the form details entered before are not getting cleared. When the logout() is performed it navigates to the Login.vue with flash message stating 'You have been logged out successfully'.

Below is the code snippet for the same:

```
  logout() {
  axios.get(`${this.host}:5000/logout`)
    .then((res) => {
      this.$store.dispatch('logout')
        .then(() => {
          this.$router.push('/login');
        });
      this.flashMessage.success({
        message: res.data.msg,
        time: 5000,
        flashMessageStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5)',
        },
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      this.flashMessage.error({
        message: error.toString(),
        time: 5000,
        flashMessageStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5)',
        },
      });
    });
}
```

logout() is written in App.vue. Here router is an instance of vue-router.
To avoid the issue of form data not being cleared I have used **router.go() instead of router.push()** in the above code. But because of this implementation, the flash message is not getting displayed as the reload (because of router.go()) is overwriting the displaying of flash message which I don't want.

Please let me if it is possible to erase the form data after logout without getting into the trouble of not showing flash message.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you have implemented Login.vue, but here is a Login.vue that I have implemented, and it works.  One of the takeaways should be that my form model data values are initialized to empty strings.

```
<template>
    <div id="login">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username" class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-2 align-right">User Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="input" ref="username" class="form-control" id="username" v-model="username">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password" class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-2 align-right">Password</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" v-model="password" v-on:keyup.enter="login">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-4">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                        v-on:click="login">Login</button>
                    <span class="error-msg" v-if="errorMsg">{{ errorMsg }}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { loginUrl, axios, processAjaxLoginError } from '../globalvars.js'

    export default {
        name: 'Login',
        data() {
            return {
                username: '',
                password: '',
                errorMsg: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            login() {
                axios.post(loginUrl, {
                    username: this.username,
                    password: this.password
                })
                .then(response => {
                    // Commit the token to the store
                    this.$store.commit('updateToken', { token: response.data.message });

                    // Clear error message
                    this.errorMsg = '';
                    
                    // Redirect to customer index view
                    this.$router.push("/customers")
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.errorMsg = processAjaxLoginError(error);
                })
            }
        },
        computed: {
            token() {
                return this.$store.state.token;
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.$refs.username.focus();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I have used the Login.vue in same manner initialized to zero. In axios .then and .catch I am displaying the message as flask message for both successful or unsuccessful login. The issue is form values are not getting cleared when logout is being called.

Comment: I haven't had to do anything special to clear the form values in my implementation.  If you can import this project (or a simplified version with the same problem) into CodeSandbox, that would help me and/or others try to diagnose what is happening.